# What does karate chop in a french bread dough mean?

Tags: baking, bread

http://www.steamykitchen.com/75-baking-the-perfect-loaf-of-french-bread.html

> Now do a little “karate chop” lengthwise down the middle of the bread and stretch out the long ends again. Fold over in half. The karate chop helps get the middle tucked inside.

I didn't understand this "karate chop" thing. What exactly does it expect me to do after I fold the sides of the dough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In context, it means to press down with the blade of your hand, to facilitate folding into thirds:

[image]

I put an orange line near the part of the hand you would press with.

This is not a standard culinary term, by the way—the recipe author is being cute.

In practice, you could use the handle of a wooden spoon, or press a little groove in with your fingers, as well.

Comment: Haha, it's not everyday you get to explain what a karate chop is on stack exchange. I really hope you were making karate noises while you were posting this

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now it seems I asked a too simple question! :(

Comment: No, it was a very strange usage in a recipe....